# Custom action_item on show page only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I'm struggling to create an action_item for a show page (not the index) of a resource. I need to add a button on the show page, which when the user clicks it, updates a single attribute on the resource (in this case 'status' of a SupportSession). I have created a method on my SupportSession model called approval_confirmed which accepts a parameter called support_session_id - I'd like this method to be called.

(BTW I'm not sure which HTTP verb to use (patch, put, get) though I've settled on patch).

Here's how my resource is set-up:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession, as: "SUSupportSession" do
```

(I've given this resource a custom name/alias because different users use this resource in different ways; so for simplicity I keep them in separate files.)

Here is my action_item code:

```
  action_item only: [:show] do
    link_to 'Approve session', approve_su_support_session_path, method: :patch
  end
```

Here is the corresponding member_action (which I understand is called by the action_item?):

```
  member_action :approve, method: :patch do
    SupportSession.with(support_session_id: resource.id).approval_confirmed
    redirect_to su_support_session_path, notice: "Your support session has been approved!"
  end
```

This creates a new route (output of rails routes below):

```
approve_su_support_session PATCH      /su_support_sessions/:id/approve(.:format)                                                 su_support_sessions#approve
```

However, when I try to open the index page (to select a record from the table and move to its show page) I get this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in SuSupportSessions#index
No route matches {:action=>"approve", :controller=>"su_support_sessions"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

I understand this is something to do with the fact that there is no id parameter on the index page (although I don't understand why it's getting called on the index page because I only need this button on the show page - where the id will appear once a user clicks 'view' on any item listed in a table).

Thanks for your help. I think I'm getting terribly mixed up with how ActiveAdmin controllers connect to the underlying model.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with ActiveAdmin but you should have some sort of variable or argument to the block available which gives you the current item in iteration (the SupportSession instance being rendered) - the example from the documentation has `post`, so maybe `approve_su_support_session_path(support_session)`? https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html

Comment: I've tried that ('support_session' as the variable/argument) and it gives the error 'undefined local variable or method'. Same for 'su_support_session' and 'susupport_session'.

Comment: Can you try `action_item only: [:show] do |*args|` and inspect `args` to see what arguments the block is called with?

Comment: Seems to be an empty array... >>  args.inspect
=> "[]"
>>

Comment: Could it be something generic like `resource`?

Comment: I tried: `link_to 'Approve session', approve_su_support_session_path(resource)` as suggested, and that resulted in a new error: `Couldn't find SupportSession without an ID`

Comment: Thats progress, so that means the link renders ok? What does the log show as the parameters when you click it?

Comment: It doesn't render. That error is another Exception: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SuSupportSessionsController#index
Couldn't find SupportSession without an ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @max says in comment above your have to pass an argument to your path, `resource` or `resource.id` works.

Regarding your current error I guess it could be caused because you have not mentionned the action you want to do.

```rb
action_item :approve, only: [:show] do
  link_to 'Approve session', approve_su_support_session_path(resource), method: :patch
end
```

I hope it helps. Let me know.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. It was driving me mad... something so simple too. So to be clear - to fix my code I added `:approve` after the `action_item` so it knew which method to call (member_action).